# What information do I give to my customers so they can pay me with PayPal?

Tags: money-transfer, paypal

If my customer want to pay me for their trip via PayPal, what do they have to know about my PayPal account?

I already share my bank account in Thailand with PayPal.

Answer (score 9):

According to the [paypal UK website](https://www.paypal-marketing.co.uk/sendmoney/index.htm):

> All you need to send money is an email address, or mobile number, and
>   PayPal will do the rest. You don't even need the person's bank
>   details.

Also, you can [send an invoice](https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=p/sell/invoicing_intro-outside) with the wanted amount. The client will receive an email with a payment button, to make the settlement they will only have to fill their billing information (as if they were buying something online).

Comment: Exactly. My email address is how people send me money, that's it.

Comment: You can now also use the paypal.me service provided to create a personal easy to type link for your business